# Where can I find out about versioned URL's in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Versioned URL's are mentioned near the bottom of this section with very little explanation:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Secure_URLs

I want to find out more about versioned URL's, but I can't seem to find any more information. My main concern has to do with disabling them. I can see how this could be useful (e.g. for debugging or postmortem), but I don't want users to be able to run previous versions of my app! Those versions might even end up corrupting data, because of data model evolution.

Is there any way to configure versioned URL's in Google App Engine?

Comment: From how I read it, the version tag is used to associate the correct version of app.yaml with the rest of that version code. Isn't the (non)presence of any non-production code an OTAP concern which is under your control?

Comment: Wha?? I'm talking about the fact that previously deployed versions can still be accessed by the public, until (as msw explains) you explicitly delete those versions from Google App Engine. Of course, I'm sure they don't actually delete the data; they just make those versions unavailable to the public. PS: not sure what you mean by "OTAP" is. None of the top results from Google seems to fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the [deployment control page](https://appengine.google.com/) for your application, you can delete prior versions under Administration ➤ Versions if you want.

The idea behind simultaneously running deployment of old versions is to not break things for earlier users who depend on old versions. By choosing the default deployment, you make users of your_app.appspot.com not care. If you want to prevent someone from running deployment 1.your_app.appspot when version 2 is up, just delete deployment 1.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the info. I guess I still don't see the utility in allowing users to run past versions arbitrarily until the site owner explicitly opts out, but I guess it could be handy (mostly for postmortem failure analysis)... It would be really cool if past versions were password protected so that only admins could view them. Even then, you have to be careful that data model evolution will not be an issue.

Comment: @allyourcode: agreed in full; one need be careful with old deployments and especially data consistency. I do believe that you could app.yaml your way into securing prior versions, but that's more than I care to muck with.